# Simple Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel

below I have coded a simple configuration manager that loads config elements from a file straight into a dictionary, and also has a function for getting an element by its key in the dictionary. I just wondered if there is anything I can do to improve this..

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Apple_Server.Application.Base.Core.Config
{
    class ConfigManager
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> configValues = null;
        private readonly FileInfo configFile = null;
        private readonly ILog _log = null;
        private bool _initialized = false;

        public ConfigManager(string filePath)
        {
            this.configValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            this.configFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
            this._log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ConfigManager));
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            if (!this._initialized)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(this.configFile.ToString()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && !s.StartsWith("#") && s.Contains("=")))
                    {
                        this.configValues[line.Split('=')[0]] = line.Split('=')[1];
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    this._log.Error("Unable to find the config file.\nPress any key to exit.");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);

                    Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opppppps");
                }
            }

            this._initialized = true;
        }

        public string GetConfigElement(string Key)
        {
            return configValues[Key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! I've added the [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] tag, so as to avoid answers that recommend things such as "well drop that and use `System.Configuration`" - feel free to rollback the edit if you didn't know about the built-in .net configuration system.

Comment: Do you know there's a [ConfigurationManager](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAAahUKEwjckdGso-PIAhUB6iYKHQotAg8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Ffr-fr%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.configuration.configurationmanager(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNF02mMqpW-PF2k0_3Ghs4pFRnyBzQ&sig2=zXzyqPEr9EdquCIM4XpOXg) in C# that works with the `app.config`?

Answer (score 6):

You're not consistent with your private fields:

> ```
> private readonly Dictionary<string, string> configValues = null;
> private readonly FileInfo configFile = null;
> private readonly ILog _log = null;
> private bool _initialized = false;
> ```

Several things:

- If you're going to use an `_underscore` prefix, then don't use a redundant `this` qualifier to refer to the field names later: it defeats the purpose.
- If you're *not* going to use an `_underscore` prefix for private fields, then don't use one *for any private field*. Be consistent. Either you `this` or you don't.
- The 3 `readonly` fields are initialized in the constructor. Why are they *also* statically initialized then?
- Why bother initializing a field to its default value? Reference types are `null`, and a `bool` is `false` by default. The static initialization is redundant.

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _configValues;
    private readonly FileInfo _configFile;
    private readonly ILog _log;
    private bool _initialized;

    public ConfigManager(string filePath)
    {
        _configValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _configFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ConfigManager));
    }
```

---

The first condition in the `Initialize` method could be inverted to eliminate a whole level of nesting:

```
if (_initialized)
{
    return;
}
```

This has the added benefit of avoiding a redundant assignment, since you don't need to set `_initialized` to `true` when it's already `true`.

---

Don't do this:

```
Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
```

The configuration manager shouldn't be allowed to terminate its client. That's a big, huge no-no right there.

Instead, throw some `ConfigurationUnavailableException` and let the client code deal with it - if it wants to terminate when configuration is unavailable, let it do so. If it wants to work off default values, *allow it to do so*. Don't just let that one component pull the plug because it's not happy with the execution path!

This isn't useful either:

> ```
> catch (Exception)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("opppppps");
> }
> ```

I'd let `System.Exception` bubble up here, and catch a more generic `System.IOException` after dealing with the `FileNotFoundException` - perhaps the file was found, but the logged-in user can't read-access it?

Ideally you would just catch `IOException` and log the exception type instead of... wait a minute. That's not a logger, it's a console wrapper! How confusing!

> ```
> this._log.Error("Unable to find the config file.\nPress any key to exit.");
> Console.ReadKey(true);
> ```

Does the user-friendly message get output to the `Console`? If so, then what do you need `ILog` for? Your class is already coupled with `System.Console`! Or it's a logger, but you're assuming the output is configured to go to the console? Logging shouldn't interact with your code in any way, and seeing "press any key to exit" in a log file is a bit awkward.

I think I'd do this instead:

```
try
{
    // load configuration
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    _log.Error(exception); // assuming overload that takes an exception.
    throw new ConfigurationUnavailableException(exception);
}
```

So we get a log trace of the actual exception, and bubble it up to the caller via a new `ConfigurationUnavailableException` that can be caught and dealt with at the call site, which would be responsible for the "press any key to continue" part.

Answer (score 5):

There is one other thing that @Mat's Mug didn't mention but it bothers me. It's this loop:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(this.configFile.ToString()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && !s.StartsWith("#") && s.Contains("=")))
{
    this.configValues[line.Split('=')[0]] = line.Split('=')[1];
}
```

The enumeration is way toooo long. You should break it and use helper variable to make it more readable and maintainable:

```
var lines = 
    File.ReadLines(configFile.ToString())
    .Where(s => 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) 
        && !s.StartsWith("#") 
        && s.Contains("=")))

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    configValues[line.Split('=')[0]] = line.Split('=')[1];
}
```

---

@Mat's Mug suggested to move the line-checking logic into a separate method. You have two choices: either a normal or an anonymous one. It then would become something like this:

```
var isConfigLine = new Func<string, bool>(line =>
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) 
    && !s.StartsWith("#") 
    && s.Contains("="));

var lines = 
    File.ReadLines(configFile.ToString())
    .Where(isConfigLine)
```

The `Where` part is now short and clean and you can easily adjust line conditions. But if you like to test it then a normal method would be better.

---

But also this index/key:

```
line.Split('=')[0]
```

it's crazy :-)

here you should also use a helper variable here:

```
var splittedLine = line.Split('=');

const int keyIndex = 0;
const int valueIndex = 1;

configValues[splittedLine[keyIndex]] = splittedLine[valueIndex];
```

Now you don't even have to think what is what because the variable names already explain everything.

Comment: Good catch! I'd even go as far as recommend extracting it into some `private static bool IsConfigurationLine(string line)` function, making it `var lines = File.ReadLines(configFile.ToString()).Where(IsConfigurationLine);`

Comment: @Mat'sMug definitely, or at least an anonymous method...